# why is my geotif bands of landsat8 is read as all zeros in python rasterio?

Tags: python, geotiff, rasterio, landsat

```
band3 = rasterio.open("/..../band3.TIF")
band6 = rasterio.open("/...../band6.TIF")

red = band3.read().astype('float')
swir = band6.read().astype('float')
```

When i try to print out after reading the values of either red or swir or even band3/band6 itself all that i get is an array of zeros. can anyone help me understand whats going on.

I tried the above code and was expecting an array with valid ranger rather than all zeros

Comment: Are you getting ALL zeros, or is it only the small subset of the edges that numpy displays?  What is the source for these images?  And if you expected integers, why do you have `astype('float')`?

Comment: Check `band3.shape` to see if it has the correct dimensions. Run your images through `exiftool` to see if they have weird compression or types.

Comment: I do believe they're ALL zeros. and the source of these .tif images are glovis. and I do get a shape of (7811, 7681)

Comment: is there any way i can check if the pixels as well are zeros despite the arrays. Lets say in a scene there are 100 pixels. can we see if all of them are zeros. Any suggestion how?

Comment: You can try `np.max(YOURARRAY)` to see the largest element.